mmap returns MAP_FAILED trying to write structs in C
I'm trying to develop a FUSE filesystem driver to create a mount point. To make it persistent I figured to save inodes into a binary file. So this is my inode struct:
struct s_fuseInode {
        int                     id; /* Identificador del inodo */
        char                    name[MAX_NAME]; /* Nombre del archivo */
        char                    path[MAX_PATH]; /* Ruta del archivo */
        int                     size; /* Tamaño del archivo */
        int                     block_count; /* Número de bloques ocupados por el archivo */
        int                     block[MAX_BLOCKS]; /* Bloques ocupados por el archivo */
        struct s_fuseInode      parent; / Inodo padre */
        int                     parent_id; /* Identificador del inodo padre */
        struct s_fuseInode      *children; / Inodos hijos */
        int                     children_count; /* Número de inodos hijos */
        int                     is_dir; /* Indica si el inodo es un directorio */
        char                    data; / Datos del archivo */
        time_t                  creation_time; /* Fecha de creación del archivo */
        time_t                  modification_time; /* Fecha de modificación del archivo */
        time_t                  access_time; /* Fecha de acceso al archivo */
        int                     links; /* Número de enlaces al archivo */
        mode_t                  mode; /* Permisos del archivo */
        uid_t    uid; /* Identificador de usuario */
        gid_t                   gid; /* Identificador de grupo */
};

And this is the function that saves the inode into the file
static int      save_inode(struct s_fuseInode *inode)
{
        int fd = open("virtual_disk.bin", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Abrimos el archivo de disco virtual
        if (fd == -1) // Si no se ha podido abrir
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al abrir el archivo de disco virtual\n");
                return (1);
        }
        off_t offset = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); // Nos situamos al final del archivo
        fprintf(stderr, "offset %ld\n", offset);
        if (offset == -1) // Si no se ha podido situar
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al situarse al final del archivo\n");
                return (1);
        }
        ftruncate(fd, offset + sizeof(struct s_fuseInode)); // Truncamos el archivo
        fprintf(stderr, "size %ld\n", offset + sizeof(struct s_fuseInode));

        struct s_fuseInode *map = mmap(0, sizeof(struct s_fuseInode), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset); // Mapeamos el archivo
        if (map == MAP_FAILED) // Si no se ha podido mapear
        {
                close(fd);
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al mapear el archivo\n");
                return (1);
        }
        memcpy(map, inode, sizeof(struct s_fuseInode)); // Copiamos el inodo en el archivo
        if (munmap(map, sizeof(struct s_fuseInode)) == -1) // Si no se ha podido desmapear
        {
                close(fd);
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al desmapear el archivo\n");
                return (1);
        }
        close(fd); // Cerramos el archivo
        return (0);
}

It returns the error of MAP_FAILED. The inode struct is 256 bits and PAGE_SIZE is 4096. I thought the problem was page alignment but I cannot see how to solve the problem, first time using mmap.
I tried including a char padding[3840] to reach 4096 size and it works, but the problem is the size that the file occupies 4KB for each inode, I want it to be optimized.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Print strerror(errno), add the output to your question. Run your program with strace, add the output to your question.

Generally, writing pointer values to a file and reading pointer values from a file is not very useful. You need to convert the tree of inodes into a serializable form.

You are looking to serialize a C struct into a disk file. Using mmap to achieve it is quite over-complicated. To optimize this, you would have to have a header for each page, pointing to the next available slot. To be updated once you added another inode of course. Like a superblock in a file system.
It would be simpler to open the file in append mode (same as seek-to-end) and write the struct directly.
Without error checking:
int fd = open("virtual_disk.bin", O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
write(fd, inode, sizeof(inode));
close(fd);

BTW:
Your struct has itself as member: struct s_fuseInode parent. This is infinitely recursive. I guess you meant it to be a pointer.


It returns the error of MAP_FAILED. The inode struct is 256 bits and PAGE_SIZE is 4096. I thought the problem was page alignment but I cannot see how to solve the problem, first time using mmap.

The struct size is definitely larger than 256 bits.  It is almost certainly larger than 256 bytes, as well.  That's not exactly the problem, but it is related.
The system page size is more relevant.  You cannot mmap() arbitrary regions of a file.  Instead, the offset you specify must be an integer multiple of the system page size.  This is your issue.
I expect that you can successfully perform the initial mapping, when the file does not exist or is empty.  But you increase the file length by exactly the size of your structure, and then on the next call you try to map starting at exactly the end of the file.  That mapping attempt fails on account of the offset not being a multiple of the page size.

It's not necessarily unreasonable to use memory mapping to access the file.  That might be especially useful when you want to update existing iNodes, which the save_inode() function you have presented cannot do.  But there are several strange things here, among them:

you are opening the file, mapping it, unmapping it again, and closing it every time you want to write an iNode.  That's terribly inefficient.  If you just want to write a new iNode at the end then you could do better by skipping the mmap() and instead just using fwrite() once you've positioned the file at its end.  Or even by opening the file in append mode, in which case you wouldn't even need to position it before writing.
But even better might be to keep the iNode file mapped, extending and re-mapping it when necessary.  That's more complicated, but it would get you something more like the performance objective that I imagine motivated your choice of mmap() in the first place.

Your iNode table is variable size.  That is not necessarily a problem, but you should consider fixing a table size when you create a filesystem.  Among other things, that would facilitate holding open a memory mapping of it, because you would not need to expand or remap it, at least not while the filesystem was on-line.  You would just create and map the full table, once, and thereafter just access iNodes as needed.

your iNode structure has multiple problems.  For one, member parent is declared as a struct s_fuseInode (a whole structure, not a pointer), which is not valid within the definition of struct s_fuseInode itself.  I imagine that you intended a pointer instead, but

pointer values are process-specific.  Therefore, it is rarely useful to write them to persistent storage.  If you want one iNode to have a reference to another, then use iNode numbers for that, not pointers.

you appear to have children in mind as being a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array of iNode structures, but this unsuitable for persistence.  Not only because pointers are unsuitable, but because the pointed-to data are variable length, and you seem to want the advantage of fixed-size iNodes.

you are storing filenames and paths in your iNodes.  This is unusual.  Filenames and paths are ordinarily a property of how iNodes are linked into a directory tree, as mediated by directories (themselves a special kind of file, not an inherent part of the underlying filesystem).  If you insist on keeping the filenames and paths inside the iNodes, then will be much larger than otherwise would be needed, plus the structure will impose a hard limit on path length.



you have pointed out that the problem arise when offset is non-zero, due I suspect to problems with page granularity and similar.
Maybe it would be OK to map the whole file, setting the mmap offset parameter to zero, and copying via memcpy just the part you need to, so you can keep the file record size minimal:
static int      save_inode(struct s_fuseInode *inode)
{
        int fd = open("virtual_disk.bin", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Abrimos el archivo de disco virtual
        if (fd == -1) // Si no se ha podido abrir
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al abrir el archivo de disco virtual: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                return (1);
        }

        // get the record size
        const size_t record_size = sizeof(struct s_fuseInode);
        fprintf(stdout, "record size  is %zu\n", record_size);

        // get the current offset into the file
        off_t current_offset = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); // Nos situamos al final del archivo
        fprintf(stderr, "file offset  is %ld\n", current_offset);

        // sanity check
        if (current_offset == -1) // Si no se ha podido situar
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al situarse al final del archivo\n");
                return (1);
        }

        // file size sanity check: must be a multiple of the record size
        if (current_offset % record_size)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "save_inodeoffste is not a multiple of base structure\n");
            return (1);
        }

        // get the record index
        const size_t record_index = (current_offset / record_size);
        fprintf(stdout, "record index is %zu\n", record_index);

        // change the file size adding room for a new record
        const int new_file_size = current_offset + record_size;
        ftruncate(fd, new_file_size); // Truncamos el archivo

        // we map the whole file and we start from zero offset to avoid problems with page granularity etc
        const int map_size          = new_file_size;
        const int mmap_file_offset  = 0;
        struct s_fuseInode *map = mmap(0, map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, mmap_file_offset); // Mapeamos el archivo
        if (map == MAP_FAILED) // Si no se ha podido mapear
        {
                close(fd);
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al mapear el archivo: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                return (1);
        }

        // copy just the bytes needed; we use the record index instead of the byte current_offset to get the destination address
        memcpy(&map[record_index], inode, record_size); // Copiamos el inodo en el archivo

        if (munmap(map, map_size) == -1) // Si no se ha podido desmapear
        {
                close(fd);
                fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al desmapear el archivo: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                return (1);
        }

        if (close(fd)){ // Cerramos el archivo
            fprintf(stderr, "save_inode: Error al serrar el archivo\n");
            return (1);
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "completed :)\n");

        return (0);
}

Output for three consecutive runs starting from file size 0:
:~/eclipse-workspace/test_posix_semaphore$ sudo Debug/test_posix_semaphore 
record size  is 273
file offset  is 0
record index is 0
completed :)
:~/eclipse-workspace/test_posix_semaphore$ sudo Debug/test_posix_semaphore 
record size  is 273
file offset  is 273
record index is 1
completed :)
:~/eclipse-workspace/test_posix_semaphore$ sudo Debug/test_posix_semaphore 
record size  is 273
file offset  is 546
record index is 2
completed :)

N.B.: your structure declaration misses some opening comment slashes.
Furthermore, maybe it would be a good idea to explicitly set the packing options for your structure via __attribute__.
struct s_fuseInode {
        int                     id; /* Identificador del inodo */
        char                    name[MAX_NAME]; /* Nombre del archivo */
        char                    path[MAX_PATH]; /* Ruta del archivo */
        int                     size; /* Tamaño del archivo */
        int                     block_count; /* Número de bloques ocupados por el archivo */
        int                     block[MAX_BLOCKS]; /* Bloques ocupados por el archivo */
        struct s_fuseInode     * parent; /* Inodo padre */
        int                     parent_id; /* Identificador del inodo padre */
        struct s_fuseInode      *children; /* Inodos hijos */
        int                     children_count; /* Número de inodos hijos */
        int                     is_dir; /* Indica si el inodo es un directorio */
        char                    data; /* Datos del archivo */
        time_t                  creation_time; /* Fecha de creación del archivo */
        time_t                  modification_time; /* Fecha de modificación del archivo */
        time_t                  access_time; /* Fecha de acceso al archivo */
        int                     links; /* Número de enlaces al archivo */
        mode_t                  mode; /* Permisos del archivo */
        uid_t                   uid;  /* Identificador de usuario */
        gid_t                   gid; /* Identificador de grupo */
}__attribute__((packed));

